# Why is a variable showing OK in Firefox but not Chrome & Safari, displays NaN?

Tags: javascript, safari, nan

I have an input with id="meetingName" and maxlength="100".
I have a listener added with Javascript that runs a Javascript function to calculate how many characters have been typed and hence how many of the 100 characters remain to be typed.
The code works fine in (Mac) Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari. In Chrome & Safari it displays NaN.

If I run the code to get the number of characters typed:

```
    var numChars = document.getElementById('meetingName').textLength;
```

... and I do a console.log(numChars) step, it shows as NaN in Safari but as 0 in Firefox (which is correct as I have yet to type any characters). I have tried it with and without using Number() to tell it to act as a number, same story either way.

If I ask what the variable type is

```
    var test1=typeof numChars
```

... and I log that to the console, it shows correctly as 'number' in both Firefox and Safari.

But if I then, immediately run isNAN() on numChars, it says it's not a number in Safari.

HTML

```
    <input type="text" id="meetingName" required maxlength="100">
```

JS

```
    // Set up a listener to count the number of characters in the Meeting Name input field
    var meetingName = document.getElementById('meetingName');
    meetingName.addEventListener("focus", meetingNameNumChars, false);
    meetingName.addEventListener("input", meetingNameNumChars, false);
    // Get max number of characters in the Meeting Name <input> field
    var maxCharsMn = Number(document.getElementById('meetingName').maxLength);
    function meetingNameNumChars() {
       var numChars = document.getElementById('meetingName').textLength;
       var test1=typeof numChars;
       console.log(test1);
       if (isNaN(numChars)) {
          console.log(numChars);
       }
       var numCharsLeft = maxCharsMn - numChars;
       document.getElementById('numCharsLeftMeetingName').innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + numCharsLeft + " characters remaining.";
    }
```

So, in the above code, I have two console.log lines:

- In Firefox it comes back as one logged item = "number" because the if statement doesn't evaluate as true
- In Safari it comes back with two consecutive logged items = "number" and then "NaN" because ... I wish I knew! I tried a parseInt(numChars) step just in case and nothing changed.

Funny enough, the same code, run on a textarea element works just fine in Firefox, Chrome & Safari.

Help much appreciated folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a cross-browser solution, use `value.length`. Take a look at a working solution below.

```js
// Set up a listener to count the number of characters in the Meeting Name input field
var meetingName = document.getElementById('meetingName');
meetingName.addEventListener("focus", meetingNameNumChars, false);
meetingName.addEventListener("input", meetingNameNumChars, false);
// Get max number of characters in the Meeting Name <input> field
var maxCharsMn = Number(document.getElementById('meetingName').maxLength);

function meetingNameNumChars() {
  var numChars = document.getElementById('meetingName').value.length;
  var numCharsLeft = maxCharsMn - numChars;
  document.getElementById('numCharsLeftMeetingName').innerHTML = numCharsLeft + " characters remaining.";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="meetingName" required maxlength="100">
<p id="numCharsLeftMeetingName"></p>
```

Comment: `textLength` is not widely supported, you can read it [here](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/HTMLTextAreaElement/textLength/). On the other hand `value` is well supported.